# How do I group an object array based on their fromTime and toTime?

Tags: javascript

I tried using lodash groupBy() but it only accepts a single parameter.

Here's a sample data :

```
let data = [
 {sign: 'open', day: 'mon', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'tue', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'wed', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'thu', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'}];
```

I want to group it like this :

```
let updated = [
 { 
  days : ['mon','wed'], 
  time : { fromTime: '1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
  sign:'open'
 },
 { 
  days : ['tue','thu'], 
  time : { fromTime: '2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'},
  sign:'open'
 },
]
```

I need to group it using fromTime and toTime only :D

Comment: You should add the code you've tried to your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Indeed, your question ought to revolve around a failed attempt to solve a problem, not the problem itself. Show us you've attempted to solve the issue at all.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right but you're also trying to group not just by time but by sign also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
let data = [
 {sign: 'open', day: 'mon', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'tue', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'wed', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'thu', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'}];
 
let result = data.reduce((m, o) => {
  var found = m.find(e => e.time.fromTime === o.fromTime && e.time.toTime === o.toTime);
  found ? found.days.push(o.day) : m.push({days: [o.day], time: {fromTime: o.fromTime, toTime: o.toTime}, sign: o.sign});
  return m;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

It's shorter by using `destructuring`:

```js
let data = [
 {sign: 'open', day: 'mon', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'tue', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'wed', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'thu', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'}];
 
let result = data.reduce((m, {sign, day, fromTime, toTime}) => {
  var found = m.find(({time}) => time.fromTime === fromTime && time.toTime === toTime);
  found ? found.days.push(day) : m.push({days: [day], time: {fromTime, toTime}, sign});
  return m;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for same groups and an array for the keys of the groups.

Then iterate and check if the key does not exist in the hash table and assign a new result set. Later push the day to the same group.

```js
let data = [{ sign: 'open', day: 'mon', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm' }, { sign: 'open', day: 'tue', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm' }, { sign: 'open', day: 'wed', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm' }, { sign: 'open', day: 'thu', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm' }],
    groups = ['fromTime', 'toTime'],
    grouped = [],
    hash = Object.create(null);
    
data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = groups.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = { days: [], time: { fromTime: o.fromTime, toTime: o.toTime }, sign: o.sign };
        grouped.push(hash[key]);
    }
    hash[key].days.push(o.day);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You COULD also write your own `groupBy` method by combining:

- `filter` (remove all unused elements)
- `map` (change the structure)
- `reduce` (combine days)

```js
let data = [
 {sign: 'open', day: 'mon', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'tue', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'wed', fromTime :'1:00 pm', toTime: '3:00 pm'},
 {sign: 'open', day: 'thu', fromTime :'2:00 pm', toTime: '6:00 pm'}];

function groupBy(fromTime, toTime) {

    return data
    .filter(d => d.fromTime === fromTime && d.toTime === toTime)
    .map(e => {
      return {
         days: [e.day],
         time: {
             fromTime: e.fromTime,
             toTime: e.toTime
         },
         sign: e.sign
      }
    })
    .reduce((f, s) => { f.days.push(s.days[0]); return f; });
}

let groupedData = [];
groupedData.push(groupBy('1:00 pm', '3:00 pm'));
groupedData.push(groupBy('2:00 pm', '6:00 pm'));

console.log(groupedData);
```